# 510(k) summary documents indicated on openFDA are not available from FDA 510(k) database

Tags: openfda

I have a question regarding the openFDA 510k data:

According to the [File Layout for Releasable 510(k)s](https://www.fda.gov/medical-devices/510k-clearances/file-layout-releasable-510ks) the `statement_or_summary` entry gives following information:

> SUMMARY indicates that a summary of safety and effectiveness
> information is available from FDA

However, for many devices with a summary entry in `statement_or_summary`, no summary document is available on the 510(k) Premarket Notification Database: e.g., for [K990380](https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfPMN/pmn.cfm?ID=K990380)

Where are these summary documents available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [FDA 510(k) Premarket Notification database](https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfpmn/pmn.cfm) misses many PDFs for items that have a `statement or summary` entry in the [openFDA 510k data file](https://open.fda.gov/data/downloads/).

I think in many cases with a missing PDF there is most likely no electronic copy available. If someone really needs these files, they could probably be recovered via a Freedom of Information Act request (FOIA).

Here the data for the /device/510k data downloaded on 2022-11-16

[image]